# How can I make this python function faster?

Tags: python, performance

The following code that I wrote takes a set of 68,000 items and tries to find similar items based on text location in the strings. The process takes a bit on this i3 4130 I'm temporarily using to code on - is there any way to speed this up? I'm making a type of 'did you mean?' function, so I need to sort on the spot of what the user enters.

I'm not trying to compare by similarity in a dictionary that's already created using keywords, I'm trying to compare the similar between the user's input on the fly and all existing keys. The user may mistype a key, so that's why it would say "did you mean?", like Google search does.

Sorting does not affect the time, according to averaged tests.

```
def similar_movies(movie):
    start=time.clock()
    movie=capitalize(movie)
    similarmovies={}
    allmovies=all_movies() #returns set of all 68000 movies
    for item in allmovies:
        '''if similar(movie.lower(),item.lower())>.5 or movie in item: #older algorithm
            similarmovies[item]=similar(movie.lower(),item.lower())'''
        if movie in item: #newer algorithm,
                similarmovies[item]=1.0
                print item
        else:
            similarmovies[item]=similar(movie.lower(),item.lower())
    similarmovieshigh=sorted(similarmovies, key=similarmovies.get, reverse=True)[:10]
    print time.clock()-start
    return similarmovieshigh
```

Other functions used:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a, b):
    output=SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
    return output

def all_movies(): #returns set of all keys in sub dicts(movies)
    people=list(ratings.keys())
    allmovies=[]
    for item in people:
        for i in ratings[item]:
            allmovies.append(i)
    allmovies=set(allmovies)
    return allmovies
```

The dictionary is in this format, except with thousands of names:

ratings={'Shane': {'Avatar': 4.2, '127 Hours': 4.7}, 'Joe': {'Into The Wild': 4.5, 'Unstoppable': 3.0}}

Comment: Sorting takes O(n log n) time to finish, usually. Are you absolutely sure you need the end result sorted?

Comment: I don't see anything terribly inefficient with your code... it might be time to start using a database. You might be able to get rid of the `sorted` call in `similar_movies` if you start storing your movies in some sort of btree so that they're sorted as you insert them.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Well, kind of; it sorts the lowest similar movies by the highest. You don't want a movie with no similarity coming up on top. It's kind of like a 'did you mean?' thing.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is going to be O(n<sup>2</sup>), since within every title, the `in` operator has to check every sub-string of the title to determine if the entered text is within it.  So yeah, I can understand why you would want this to run faster.

An i3 doesn't provide much compute power, so pre-computing as much as possible is the only solution, and running extra software such as a database is probably going to provide poor results, again due to the capability.

You might consider using a dictionary of title words (possibly with pre-computed phonetic changes to eliminate most common misspellings - the Porter Stemmer algorithm should provide some helpful reduction rules, e.g. to allow "unstop" to match "unstoppable").

So, for example, one key in your dictionary would be "wild" (or a phonetic adjustment), and the value associated with that key would be a list of all titles that contain "wild"; you would have the same for "the", "into", "avatar", "hours", "127", and all other words in your list of 68,000 titles.  Just as an example, your dictionary's "wild" entry might look like:

```
"wild": ["Into The Wild", "Wild Wild West", "Wild Things"]
```

(Yes, I searched for "wild" on IMDB just so this list could have more entries - probably not the best choice, but not many titles have "avatar", "unstoppable", or "hours" in them).

Common words such as "the" might have enough entries that you would want to exclude them, so a persistent copy of the dictionary might be helpful to allow you to make specific adjustments, although it isn't necessary, and the compute time should be relatively quick at start-up.

When the user types in some text, you split the text into words, apply any phonetic reductions if you choose to use them, and then concatenate all of the title lists for all of the words from the user, including duplicates.

Then, count the duplicates and sort by how many times a title was matched.  If a user types "The Wild", you'd have two matches on "Into The Wild" ("the" and "wild"), so it should sort higher than titles with only "the" or "wild" but not both in them.

Your list of ratings can be searched after the final sorted list is built, with ratings appended to each entry; this operation should be quick, since your ratings are already within a dictionary, keyed by name.

This turns an O(n<sup>2</sup>) search into a O(log(n)) search for each word entered, which should make a big difference in performance, if it suits your needs.

Comment: @TrivisionZero and as Matt's answer shows you are very far from efficient in your algorithms. The suggestions he makes are not simple especially if you are a beginner, but they are what will turn your brute-force approach into an elegant solution.

Comment: @msw I understand what Matt is trying to suggest, but that's not how users will enter the input, or at least how I think. I'm trying to plan in the case that the user mistypes the movie title, that's why I compare similarity of strings, not by keyword. If the input is "th3 wild", nothing would come up.

Comment: "th3 wild" would result in matching "wild" but not "the", so yes, something would come up; is your "newer algorithm" temporary then, and you plan to return to the SequenceMatcher implementation instead?

Answer (score 1):

In `all_movies()`: instead of appending to a list you could add to a set and not cast keys() to a list:

```
def all_movies():
    allmovies = set()
    for item in ratings.keys():
        for i in ratings[item]:
            allmovies.add(i)
    return allmovies
```

EDIT: or only using one for-loop:

```
def all_movies():
    result = []
    for rating_dict in ratings.values()
        result += rating_dict.keys()
    return result
```

Nothing I could spot in `similar_movies`.

Also have a look at celery: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/ for multi-processing,
especially the `chunks` concept: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chunks

Comment: Actually, I was looking at different ways to add to a list, and it seems that this: `allmovies+=i` is the fastest. Your code took 2.25 seconds consistently and the `+=i` took on average 1.3 seconds. Is there any way quicken this even more? Maybe take out the second for loop and just add the entire list each time?

Comment: @TrivisionZero: I added another aproach based on you comment.

Comment: The format mentioned in the question is actually `ratings[rating_list].values()`, as it's actually full of subdicts. Even correcting for that is still as slow or slower for some reason.

Comment: @TrivisionZero: I changed it to expect a dict of dicts, this should work (at least it does for the example in your question) :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing for a production system, I'd suggest using a full text search engine like [Whoosh (Python)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/), [Elastic Search (Java)](https://www.elastic.co/), or [Apache Solr (Java)](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/). A full text search engine is a server that builds an index to implement full text search including fuzzy or proximity searches efficiently. Many popular database system also features full search text engine like [PostgreSQL FTS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch.html) and [MySQL FTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) that may be an acceptable alternative if you are already using these database engines.

If this code is developed mostly for self learning and you want to learn how to implement fuzzy searches, you may want to look at normalizing the movie titles in the index and the search terms. There are methods like [Soundex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) and [Metaphone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone) that normalizes search terms based on how it likely sounds in English and this normalized term can be used to create the search index. PostgreSQL have [implementation of these algorithms](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/fuzzystrmatch.html). Note that these algorithms are very basic building blocks, a proper full text search engine will take into account misspelling, synonyms, stop words, language specific quirks, and optimizations like parallel/distributed processing, etc.